# Javascript Contact API - how do I 'do something' with results

Tags: api, javascript

Through javascript, I was hoping to check what groups a user belongs to and then use that information to show / hide something. I can't use ACLs because I'd like the average internal user to be able to enter the information on intake but not be able to edit it in future.

Using the API, I can get an object that has a

```
    CRM.api3('Contact', 'get', {
  "return": "group",
  "id": 68525 // arbitrary number will need current user
}).done(function(result) {
  // do something
    console.log(result);

});
```

which returns this

```
Object { is_error: 0, version: 3, count: 1, id: 68525, values: Object }
```

The group info **is in** the values: Objects, how can I reference it?

Comment: Did you try console.log(result.values); ?

Comment: Similar result: Object { 68525: Object } In the console I can see inside that nested object, it holds the groups info, I just have no idea how to get to it.

Comment: You can also iterate with a loop if you don't know the id, e.g. for (var i in result.values) { // do something with result.values[i] } Can also search the internet for general javascript howtos.

Comment: Yes, I did search the internet, but was struggling for the right search terms, I thought perhaps someone here had done something similar and could offer advice. I figured it out for myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the 'groups' result from the returned 'result' - I had to access the nested data. I referenced this great explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json

I still struggled for a bit and realized that's because the groups result i was looking for was nested down two levels.

```
result Object { is_error: 0, version: 3, count: 1, id: 68525, values: Object }

   values Object { 68525: Object }

       68525 Object { contact_id: "68525", groups: "Administrators", id: "68525" }
```

On top of that to reference that last object by a number i had to enclose on quotes.

I still have work to do towards my ultimate functionality but my proof of concept holds true.

Here's what I ultimately used to get the contents of 'groups':

```
console.log(result['values']['68525']['groups']);
```